# .htaccess ModRewrite question

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

trying to do rewrite rule  for this:
http://website.com/checkreg/34324234     <--- Old URL Location

to this: 
http://website.com/chkreg.php?checkreg=34324234  <--- New URL Address

I've tried the following, but it causes an error 500 message, I don't know enough about ModRewrite to figure out the issue.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^checkreg/([^/]*)$ /chkreg.php?checkreg=$1 [L] 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: A 500 message sounds like you have an error in your chkreg.php program.  Does it run correctly if you access it with the un-rewritten URL?

Comment: I can access website.com/chkreg.php?checkreg=45345345 directly without issue, but when I go to website.com/checkreg/34324234 I get an error 500. I'm checking logs now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sounds like a rewriteEngine issue. You could try to remove the rewriteEngine on directive, to give a try (if it's already enabled) but I don't think much of it.
But what does the errorlog say?

Comment: when I remove the rewriteEngine On it doesn't turn on the rewriteEngine so I know it's not being loaded twice somehow.  Also, the error log, it would give me an error 500 if I put the error log info in the htaccess, so I'm trying to put it in http.conf

Answer (score 1):

You said you want to rewrite from http://website.com/chkreg.php?checkreg=34324234
to http://website.com/checkreg/34324234, but your rewrite rule is doing the opposite.

Use this:

```
RewriteRule ^chkreg.php?checkreg=(.*) /checkreg/$1 [L]
```

Edit: If you need further debugging information from mod_rewrite then add the following:

```
RewriteLog /your/path/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Comment: I still get an error 500 with your fix, but thank for telling me about it being backwards.  I used a .htaccess generator website to make it.. :P

Comment: I actuall want to rewrite from http://website.com/checkreg/34324234 to http://website.com/chkreg.php?checkreg=34324234 because there are a lot of copies of the software pointing to the old checkreg.

Comment: Then your original rule looks correct. You should check the rewrite logs to see what is going on. Are you able to use the checkreg/34324234 url directly?

Comment: When your rule is 'RewriteRule A B' that means people type 'A' in their browser and you want them to access 'B' on your server.

Comment: I can access website.com/chkreg.php?checkreg=45345345 directly without issue, but when I go to website.com/checkreg/34324234 I get an error 500. I'm checking logs now. Thanks for the help so far.